# Read unformatted csv, and convert to formated csv via php script

Tags: php, excel, csv, macros

The Goal is to extract data of a specified column or CSV using PHP,

I have a unformatted CSV.
I format this csv using Excel Feature: Data->Import Data from Text,
(Using delimiter and tab as a separator) it format the data into columns.
For this i have created a Excel Macro.

Any ideas on how to execute excel macro via php script?
That code will execute the Macro and CSV will be well formatted and then i can get the data.
Any help will be highly appreciated.

Comment: Excel sheets are mostly on clients, whereas PHP runs mostly on servers. So PHP won't have access to the sheet by itself. Which scenario do you imagine?

Comment: Hi Tam, We will put the file on server and we need to do all the things on server. if is there any third party library we need to use we will install it on the server too.